# Unique fields in table Fluent Api / Code First

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, unique-index

I have been looking for a way to make, for example a username unique in the database with `Fluent API` / `Code First`. Is this even possible via either of these routes?

Because I can't find any tutorial or example that shows how this is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to provide a Context Initializer and override Seed method to initialize your database. There you can add an Unique Index using **DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand**. Here is the sample code for the same.

**Model**

```
public class Relay  {

    //Scalar Properties
    private int _id;
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id {
        get { return _id; }
        set { SetField(ref _id, value, () => Id); }
    }

    private string _name;
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Required]
    public virtual string Name {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetField(ref _name, value, () => Name); }
    }

    //Other properties of Model
}
```

**DBContext**

```
public class RelayContext : DbContext {
     public DbSet<Relay> Relays { get; set; }

    public RelayContext(string connectionString) : 
        base(connectionString) {
        Database.SetInitializer(new RelayContextInitializer());
    }
}
```

**ContextInitializer**

```
public class RelayContextInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<RelayContext> {
    protected override void Seed(RelayContext context) {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Uix_Relay_Name ON Relays(Name)");
    }
}
```

That's it. You have now an Unique Index created on Name field of Relays Table.

Comment: Hi, can't i use the tables created with Code First instead of Relay? I'm not sure what that is suppose to do. Can't ExecuteSqlCommand() be called directly?

Comment: Relays is the name of the Table that I had used. Substitute it with your Table name. The index creation is one time job and is best handled by Context Initializers.